# redis transaction: how to lpush the result of rpop of a list?

Tags: node.js, redis

If I have a list and exec :

```
step 1 : rpop 
step 2 : lpush
```

I want to keep round in my list and avoid data loss, I think its about transaction question, how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rpoplpush, I should read more offical documents.  https://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush